# How does a predictive coding aid in lossless compression?

Tags: image-processing, compression, huffman-code

I'm working on this lab where we need to apply a lossless predictive coding to an image before compressing it (with Huffman, or some other lossless compression algorithm).

From the example seen below, it's pretty clear that by pre-processing the image with predictive coding, we've modified its histogram and concentrated all of its grey levels around 0. But why exactly does this aid compression?

Is there maybe a formula to determine the compression rate of Huffman, knowing the standard deviation and entropy of the original image? Otherwise, why would the compression ratio be any different; it's not like the range of values has changed between the original image and pre-processed image.

[image]

Thank you in advance,

Liam.

Comment: Huffman is an encoding...

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, but by pre-processing the image with predictive coding, it supposedly improves the compression ratio when doing Huffman or any other type of variable length compression.

Comment: “concentrated all of its grey levels around 0”. The keyword is “concentrated”. There are many more pixels now with identical values, and the total range might be the same, but the tails are much thinner. That helps Huffman encoding by making the most used values even more common, and the less used ones even less common. Do you understand how Huffman encoding works?